# Strange crash, analyzing in gdb

Tags: c++, crash, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I have an application and I am analyzing memory crash dumps of this software.

```
struct GPS_CONNECTION
{
    int sockfd;
    std::string sendbuf, recvbuf;
    struct sockaddr_in remoteaddr;
};
vector <GPS_CONNECTION> GPSC;

--------------------------------
(cut)
--------------------------------

fd_set master, gps_master, read_fds, gps_read_fds, write_fds, gps_write_fds;

for (;;)
{
    /* Clear */
    FD_ZERO(&gps_read_fds);
    FD_ZERO(&gps_write_fds);

    /* read_fds */
    gps_read_fds = gps_master;

    /* write_fds */
    for (int i=0; i < GPSC.size(); i++)
    {
        if (GPSC[i].sendbuf.empty())
        {
            continue;
        }
        FD_SET(GPSC[i].sockfd, &gps_write_fds);
    }

    /* Timeout struct */
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    /* selectuj write */
    if (select(gps_fdmax+1, &gps_read_fds, &gps_write_fds, NULL, &tv) == -1)
    {
        perror("select");
        return 7;
    }

    --------------------------------
    (cut)
    --------------------------------
}
```

GDB crash dump says software is crashed in line:

```
443                 if (GPSC[i].sendbuf.empty())
```

When I was analyzing the variables I saw this:

```
(gdb) print i
$1 = -1214807923
```

I don't understand how this value was overwritten? I don't see any stack overflow issue here, can anyone explain the reason of this crash?

This problem appears recurring - once in 2-days, this is a server working 24/7/365.

---

After g++ expanding this code that results:

```
 for (int i=0; i < GPSC.size(); i++)
 {
     if (GPSC[i].sendbuf.empty())
     {
         continue;
     }
     __asm__ __volatile__ ("btsl %1,%0" : "=m" (((&gps_write_fds)->fds_bits)[((GPSC[i].sockfd) / (8 * sizeof (__fd_mask)))]) : "r" (((int) (GPSC[i].sockfd)) % (8 * sizeof (__fd_mask))) : "cc","memory");
 }
```

Comment: What does `GPSC` contain? What type of structure is it?

Comment: What is the usual size of GPSC? Is this problem recurring, or one-time only?

Comment: Possibly an overflow? vector.size() returns an unsigned while you are using a signed int.

Comment: One random possibility is that `gps_write_fds` is the wrong size, and as a result `i` gets clobbered by `FD_SET`?

Comment: Good thought - Svisstack, can you show more code before the `for` loop? Specifically as Ernest suggests, the `gps_write_fds` variable.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: Wouldn't that require some casting to force FD_SET to accept a pointer of invalid type? Assuming FD_SET is a function and not a macro... Printing `i` each time the loop body is run could show something useful. Also, what's that `.` between the for header and the loop body?

Comment: @rafałRawicki: This problem appears recurring - once a 2-days, this is a server working 24/7/365.

Comment: @DCoder: `FD_SET()` is normally a macro.

Comment: @Svisstack -- you don't actually show the data type in the declaration of `gps_write_fds`. Is it `fd_set`, as it should be?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: i posted code after expaind macro

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: definition of `gps_write_fds` was showne before `for`

Comment: How do you calculate `gps_fdmax`?

Comment: @DCoder: `gps_fdmax = max(gps_fdmax, newfd);`, when new connection was appear.

Comment: Based only on a brief look at the `select` documentation, it seems to me that `gps_fdmax + 1` shouldn't have that `+ 1` in it, and you should make sure that it doesn't exceed whatever underlying limits are in effect (`FD_SETSIZE`).

Comment: @DCoder: you mean that is related with that problem with value of i variable in while above?

Comment: `select` will potentially write to both `gps_read_fds` and `gps_write_fds`, and `gps_write_fds` is likely to be right next to `i` on the stack. If you tell `select` it can write to more bytes than `gps_write_fds` takes up, it could overwrite other data, such as `i`. But again, I have no practical experience with `select` programming, just read the documentation, so I might be talking nonsense.

Comment: @DCoder: but select is after that code who are failing because some undefined behaviour.

Comment: OK, I take that back, that overflow doesn't seem likely. But the part about not exceeding `FD_SETSIZE` should still be considered everywhere you call into `FD_*` functions, just for correctness' sake. Next time you catch this in GDB, you might want to look at all `sockfd`s in `GPSC` and see how large they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code will crashing because of multi-threading that i will not consider before, i think that is working in one thread only, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

From the small code snippet you shared, it's hard to say what the problem really is.

I can only suspect that the result of `GPSC.size()` is bigger than what an `int` can store, therefore causing an overflow on `i` after *some* iterations.

Comment: In this vector are placed one connection, in for debug proposes this are vector because while debugging some second connection can appear.

Comment: @Svisstack "Some second connection can appear"---this suggests threads.  If another thread can modify `GPSC`, then you'll have to protect all accesses to it.

Comment: @JamesKanze: This is one thread loop, i thinking about that but only one thread working this is a main process, all socket communication code is placed in this thread using select with non blocking usage, when next connection was appear then on select connection was created and placed on this vector. This is not possible to do this code with same thread in same time.